# declaring function with an object parameter

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
#ifndef AI_H
#define AI_H

void BuildTree(Board b);
int getMove();
void acceptMove(int);


#endif
```

and the cpp file:

```
#include "AI.h"
#include "Board.h"

void BuildTree(Board b)
{

}

int getMove()
{

    return 0;
}
void acceptMove(int)
{

}
```

I am getting an error because of the paramater `Board b` in the header file.
the error is:

`Error  1   error C2065: 'Board' : undeclared identifier`

why is it not accepting an object?? I want the function to receive an object by value, not reference.

Comment: If you want to pass by value, you need it included in the header.

Comment: A forward declaration is also fine for declaring a function taking a type by value. You don't need the type fully defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is complaining about Board: it does not know what is it. You must define (not only declare) it to be able to use an object of that type (e.g. taking it as parameter).

You can solve your issue by `#include`ing the header file defining `Board` :

```
#include "Board.h"
```

Comment: I see, I have to include it in both header and cpp file.Another thing though, the received argument will be a copy correct?? even if board has 2D arrays in it?

Comment: @AmmarSamater you need to include it only in header file.

Comment: @AmmarSamater You should only include it in AI.h since you include AI.h from AI.cpp ;) And yes, this is correct: `BuildTree` will receive a copy of the `Board`. If you *do* need a copy that's great. If you need only to read a Board, `BuildTree` shoud get a `const Board&` as parameter. Finally, if you need to read and write to the Board object, it shoud take a `Board&` reference. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Just include `Board.h` in `ai.h`:

```
#ifndef AI_H
#define AI_H

#include "Board.h"

void BuildTree(Board b);
int getMove();
void acceptMove(int);

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Include `Board.h` in your first file, `AI.h`